# How to interpret a small regression coefficient with a p-value of 0.01 in an OLS model?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, interpretation, regression-coefficients, effect-size

I have built a multiple regression and estimated it using OLS.  All the variables are significant. One of the coefficients is close to zero (around 0.0003) with a significant p-value of 0.01. How to interpret that?

Comment: How many variables and how many observations do you have?

Comment: 4 variables(all are significant, including this), around 60 data points

Comment: Basically there are three possibilities to explain this. (1) You have very many observations so that even a very small effect is significant (doesn't seem the case here), (2) Units of measurements and observed values of x and y are so that even 0.0003 is in fact not that small an effect (see answer by @PatrickCoulombe) or (3) for some reason observations are very precisely on a low dimensional hyperplane, so that the error variance is around zero and all coefficients can be estimated extremely precisely.

Comment: @Christian Hennig, the P-value of this variable is insignificant after the Newey-west test because the residual is autocorrelated and hetroscadesticy

Answer (score 7):

The unstandardized estimate is fully dependent on the scale of the predictor: it's interpreted as the expected change in y **for each 1-unit increase in x**. If you rescale x (with a linear transformation), you will obtain the same p-value but the coefficient will be different. For example if you divide your x by 1000, the coefficient will multiply by 1000.

For example, in R:

**x is left as is:**

```r
> lm(y1 ~ x1, df) |> summary()

Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ x1, data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.24561 -0.30359  0.04108  0.28450  1.42058 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 0.007912   0.019625   0.403    0.687    
x1          0.745828   0.034805  21.428   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4388 on 498 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4797,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4787 
F-statistic: 459.2 on 1 and 498 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

**x is divided by 1000:**

```r
> lm(y1 ~ I(x1/1000), df) |> summary()

Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ I(x1/1000), data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1.24561 -0.30359  0.04108  0.28450  1.42058 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 7.912e-03  1.963e-02   0.403    0.687    
I(x1/1000)  7.458e+02  3.481e+01  21.428   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4388 on 498 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4797,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.4787 
F-statistic: 459.2 on 1 and 498 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: How to interpret when the confidence interval of the estimate includes 0 for this variable

Comment: That doesn't sound possible. The confidence interval and the hypothesis test should match exactly. Perhaps you could show your output and give more detail about the analysis you're running.

Comment: yes, that was my mistake. I will delete the comment.